# How can I change the Double value in my dictionary outside the function?

Tags: ios, swift, function, dictionary, swift2

```
var grades: [String : Double]

grades = ["A": 0.0, "A-": 0.0, "B+": 0.0, "B": 0.0, "B-": 0.0, "C+": 0.0, "C": 0.0, "C-": 0.0, "D+": 0.0, "D": 0.0, "D-": 0.0, "F": 0.0]

func calcGPA() {

if let a = grades["A"], amin = grades["A-"], bplu = grades["B+"], b = grades["B"], bmin = grades["B-"], cplu = grades["C+"], c = grades["C"], cmin = grades["C-"], dplu = grades["D+"], d = grades["D"],    dmin = grades["D-"], f = grades["F"] {

        // Divide by this
        let gradesAdded = a + amin + bplu + b + bmin + cplu + c + cmin + dplu + d + dmin + f
        //grades multiplied by their values and added ex. a * 4.0 + amin * 3.7
        let gradesCalculated = a * 4.0 + amin * 3.7 + bplu * 3.3 + b * 3.0 + bmin * 2.7 + cplu * 2.3 + c *  2.0 + cmin * 1.7 + dplu * 1.3 + d * 1.0 + dmin * 0.7 // Dont do F because it would just add 0
        var gpa = gradesCalculated / gradesAdded

        if gpa.isNaN {
            gpa = 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like grades["A"] += 1.0 so that it goes up by one and I can call calcGPA()? I can't figure out how to make this work. Any help on this would be awesome

Comment: Take a look at operator overloading in Swift. Here's a reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase a value in your dictionary by force unwrapping the lookup:

```
grades["A"]! += 1.0
```

but this is dangerous because it will crash if the key isn't in the dictionary.  So, you should check:

```
if let count = grades["A"] {
    grades["A"] = count + 1
}
```

Here is an updated version of your program:

```
func calcGPA(_ termGrades: [String]) -> Double? {

    var grades: [String: Double] = ["A": 0.0, "A-": 0.0, "B+": 0.0, "B": 0.0, "B-": 0.0, "C+": 0.0, "C": 0.0, "C-": 0.0, "D+": 0.0, "D": 0.0, "D-": 0.0, "F": 0.0]

    var gpa: Double?
    
    for grade in termGrades {
        if let count = grades[grade] {
            grades[grade] = count + 1
        } else {
            print("Hmmm, \(grade) is not a valid value for a grade")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    if let a = grades["A"], amin = grades["A-"], bplu = grades["B+"], b = grades["B"], bmin = grades["B-"], cplu = grades["C+"], c = grades["C"], cmin = grades["C-"], dplu = grades["D+"], d = grades["D"], dmin = grades["D-"], f = grades["F"] {
        
        // Divide by this
        let gradesAdded = a + amin + bplu + b + bmin + cplu + c + cmin + dplu + d + dmin + f
        //grades multiplied by their values and added ex. a * 4.0 + amin * 3.7
        let gradesCalculated = a * 4.0 + amin * 3.7 + bplu * 3.3 + b * 3.0 + bmin * 2.7 + cplu * 2.3 + c *  2.0 + cmin * 1.7 + dplu * 1.3 + d * 1.0 + dmin * 0.7 // Dont do F because it would just add 0

        gpa = gradesAdded == 0 ? nil : gradesCalculated / gradesAdded
    }
    return gpa
}

// example calls
calcGPA(["E"])             // nil  "Hmmm, E is not a valid value for a grade"
calcGPA(["A-"])            // 3.7
calcGPA(["A", "B"])        // 3.5
calcGPA(["B", "B+", "A-"]) // 3.333333333333333
calcGPA([])                // nil
```

---

#### Notes:

1. I changed your function to take an array of grades and return a `Double?` (Optional `Double`).
2. `nil` is returned if anything goes wrong (input array is empty, input array contains invalid grade such as "E").
3. *Divide by zero* is avoided ahead of time by checking the divisor before the calculation.

---

#### Alternate Solution:

And now for something completely different...

Inspired by @CodeBender's comment, here is an implementation that uses an `enum` with an associated value to represent the grades:

```
enum Grade: Double {
    case A = 4.0
    case Aminus = 3.7
    case Bplus = 3.3
    case B = 3.0
    case Bminus = 2.7
    case Cplus = 2.3
    case C = 2.0
    case Cminus = 1.7
    case Dplus = 1.3
    case D = 1.0
    case Dminus = 0.7
    case F = 0
}

func calcGPA(_ termGrades: [Grade]) -> Double? {
    if termGrades.count == 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        let total = termGrades.reduce(0.0) { (total, grade) in total + grade.rawValue }
        return total / Double(termGrades.count)
    }
}

// example calls
calcGPA([.A, .B])              // 3.5
calcGPA([.B, .Bplus, .Aminus]) // 3.3333333333
calcGPA([.A, .A, .Bplus])      // 3.7666666666
calcGPA([.F, .F, .F])          // 0
calcGPA([])                    // nil
```

Comment: Would recommend doing away with the entire dictionary and replacing it with an enum. You get type safety, and can assign the values to it as well & then reference the enum raw value (ex: Grade.A.rawValue)

Comment: I agree @CodeBender.  I tried to stay with the spirit of the question, but introducing an enum is an excellent way to go.

Comment: Very nice! Maybe return an optional on the function though to avoid confusion between no values and a stellar scholar?

Comment: Thank you for the help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just one thing I am not familiar with .reduce

Comment: `reduce` is a function that iterates over the values of the collection (array).  `reduce` takes two parameters: an initial value and a closure that gets run on each item.  Here, I use it to produce the sum of the grades.  It works like this: for the first grade in the array, `0.0` is passed to the closure as the initial value for the `total` and `grade` receives the first item in the array.  The closure takes the `rawValue` of the grade and adds it to the current running `total` and returns that value.  That total is then passed into the closure with the second grade from the array.

Comment: ... and the process repeats until the final result of reduce is the total of all of the grades.

Comment: It is pretty much equivalent to:  `var total = 0.0; for grade in termGrades { total += grade.rawValue }`.